# Numpy array to raster with ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, python, netcdf, numpy

I have a Python script to download data in `netCFD` format. I have managed to extract the information I need in a masked array. This looks like:

```
print(my_array.shape())
>> (700, 299, 217)
```

As a working example I have selected only the first array of the first dimension, such as:

```
data = my_array[0][0]
print (data.shape())
>> (299,217)
```

This is stored as a masked array by default, this means that some of the values are empty. I am trying to export this to a raster file, so it looks like the image below [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjaTa.png). The array looks likes [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a17Zu.png):

[image: I want this]
[image: array]

However, with the following code (see below) the raster is saved as the second picture [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqgYh.png). The empty values in my array are stored as 2.147483648000000000e+09. See [attached filed.](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1fQu5hRaTyaqcT1LW_maaZCOOHiT_9isN?usp=sharing)

```
np.savetxt('raster.txt', data)
```

or

```
data_1 = np.ma.masked_array(data, fill_value=None)
np.savetxt('raster.txt', data_1)
```

What I do next is with `arcpy`

```
import os
import sys
import numpy as np
import arcpy

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.env.outputCoordinateSystem = arcpy.SpatialReference('WGS 1984')
nraster = np.genfromtxt('raster.txt', missing_values='Null')
cell_size = 0.041666667
lat = 18.020833333333343
lon = -104.97916666666666
corner = arcpy.Point(lat, lon)

# Convert array to a geodatabase raster
my_raster = arcpy.NumPyArrayToRaster(nraster, corner, x_cell_size=cell_size, y_cell_size=cell_size)    
my_raster.save('working_path/GDB.gdb/my_raster')
```

[image: It looks like this]

So my question is, **how can I save this array to a .txt file (in Python) so I can read it back with `arcpy.NumPyArrayToRaster` and continue my process in ArcMap?**

Comment: I added my question at the bottom.

Comment: Does [this](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) answer your question?

Comment: Your problem is not GIS related since you get strange values in the textfile and is probably more likely to get answered on stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0):

Your data is weird:

```
nraster.mean()
266437204.71322224
nraster.max()
2147483648.0
np.median(nraster)
22.6
```

So you have many values around 22 which the very large mean/max "hides". If you do:

```
nraster = np.where(nraster>100,100,nraster)
```

And apply a stretch you get something:
[image]

What mean/max/median do you get on the original numpy array?

Comment: I have 

`max = 155.9
median = 22.6
mean = 31.443140428976122`

You get different results because, as max you are considering what I wrote is set as default `2.147483648000000000e+09`

Comment: Then something goes wrong when you create the txt file. Why do you need this step? Use the correct numpy array as input to NumpyArrayToRaster

Comment: Yes, I know something is going wrong. But when I use `np.savetxt` the txt contain a large number for empty rows.

Comment: As the question is on hold by some weird reason. I will post the answer to this in my github. It is a problem related to GIS/Python/ArcMap.